# Microphone not working on dell precision 5480, 22.04

Tags: sound, dell, microphone

I have a Dell precision 5480 running Ubuntu 22.04, and the microphone is not working. In pavucontrol something appears as "sof-soundwire SoundWire microphones" but it does not detect any sound, and I don't get whether it really correspond to a physical microphone? In alsamixer everything seems to be unmuted.

```
inxi -A                                               
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel driver: intel-ipu6
  Device-2: Intel driver: sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl
  Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k6.5.0-25-generic running: yes
  Sound Server-2: PulseAudio v: 15.99.1 running: yes
  Sound Server-3: PipeWire v: 0.3.48 running: yes
```

arecord -l:

```
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 0: sofsoundwire [sof-soundwire], device 1: Jack In (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: sofsoundwire [sof-soundwire], device 4: Microphone (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

(shortened) alsa info script:

```
!!################################
!!ALSA Information Script v 0.5.3
!!################################

!!Script ran on: Mon Mar  4 15:02:43 UTC 2024


!!Linux Distribution
!!------------------

Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS \n \l DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS" PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS" NAME="Ubuntu" ID=ubuntu ID_LIKE=debian HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/" SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/" BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/" PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy" UBUNTU_CODENAME=jammy


!!DMI Information
!!---------------

Manufacturer:      Dell Inc.
Product Name:      Precision 5480
Product Version:   
Firmware Version:  1.7.0
System SKU:        0C40
Board Vendor:      Dell Inc.
Board Name:        03JVP1


!!Kernel Information
!!------------------

Kernel release:    #21~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Feb  9 13:32:52 UTC 2
Operating System:  GNU/Linux
Architecture:      x86_64
Processor:         x86_64
SMP Enabled:       Yes


!!ALSA Version
!!------------

Driver version:     k6.5.0-21-generic
Library version:    1.2.6.1
Utilities version:  1.2.6


!!Loaded ALSA modules
!!-------------------

snd_soc_sof_sdw (card 0)


!!Sound Servers on this system
!!----------------------------

PipeWire:
      Installed - Yes (/usr/bin/pipewire)
      Running - Yes

Pulseaudio:
      Installed - Yes (/usr/bin/pulseaudio)
      Running - Yes


!!Soundcards recognised by ALSA
!!-----------------------------

 0 [sofsoundwire   ]: sof-soundwire - sof-soundwire
                      Intel Soundwire SOF


!!PCI Soundcards installed in the system
!!--------------------------------------

00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller [0401]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:51ca] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:0c40]


!!Modprobe options (Sound related)
!!--------------------------------

snd_pcsp: index=-2
snd_usb_audio: index=-2
snd_atiixp_modem: index=-2
snd_intel8x0m: index=-2
snd_via82xx_modem: index=-2
snd_atiixp_modem: index=-2
snd_intel8x0m: index=-2
snd_via82xx_modem: index=-2
snd_usb_audio: index=-2
snd_usb_caiaq: index=-2
snd_usb_ua101: index=-2
snd_usb_us122l: index=-2
snd_usb_usx2y: index=-2
snd_cmipci: mpu_port=0x330 fm_port=0x388
snd_pcsp: index=-2
snd_usb_audio: index=-2


!!Loaded sound module options
!!---------------------------

!!Module: snd_soc_sof_sdw
    quirk : -1


!!Sysfs card info
!!---------------

!!Card: /sys/class/sound/card0
Driver: /sys/bus/platform/drivers/sof_sdw
Tree:
    /sys/class/sound/card0
    |-- controlC0
    |   |-- dev
    |   |-- device -> ../../card0
    |   |-- led-mic -> ../../../../../../virtual/sound/ctl-led/mic/card0
    |   |-- led-speaker -> ../../../../../../virtual/sound/ctl-led/speaker/card0
    |   |-- power
    |   |-- subsystem -> ../../../../../../../class/sound
    |   `-- uevent
    |-- device -> ../../../sof_sdw
    |-- hwC0D2
    |   |-- afg
    |   |-- chip_name
    |   |-- clear
    |   |-- dev
    |   |-- device -> ../../card0
    |   |-- driver_pin_configs
    |   |-- hints
    |   |-- init_pin_configs
    |   |-- init_verbs
    |   |-- mfg
    |   |-- modelname
    |   |-- power
    |   |-- power_off_acct
    |   |-- power_on_acct
    |   |-- reconfig
    |   |-- revision_id
    |   |-- subsystem -> ../../../../../../../class/sound
    |   |-- subsystem_id
    |   |-- uevent
    |   |-- user_pin_configs
    |   |-- vendor_id
    |   `-- vendor_name
    |-- id
    |-- input20
    |   |-- capabilities
    |   |-- device -> ../../card0
    |   |-- event15
    |   |-- id
    |   |-- inhibited
    |   |-- modalias
    |   |-- name
    |   |-- phys
    |   |-- power
    |   |-- properties
    |   |-- subsystem -> ../../../../../../../class/input
    |   |-- uevent
    |   `-- uniq
    |-- input21
    |   |-- capabilities
    |   |-- device -> ../../card0
    |   |-- event16
    |   |-- id
    |   |-- inhibited
    |   |-- modalias
    |   |-- name
    |   |-- phys
    |   |-- power
    |   |-- properties
    |   |-- subsystem -> ../../../../../../../class/input
    |   |-- uevent
    |   `-- uniq
    |-- input22
    |   |-- capabilities
    |   |-- device -> ../../card0
    |   |-- event17
    |   |-- id
    |   |-- inhibited
    |   |-- modalias
    |   |-- name
    |   |-- phys
    |   |-- power
    |   |-- properties
    |   |-- subsystem -> ../../../../../../../class/input
    |   |-- uevent
    |   `-- uniq
    |-- input23
    |   |-- capabilities
    |   |-- device -> ../../card0
    |   |-- event18
    |   |-- id
    |   |-- inhibited
    |   |-- modalias
    |   |-- name
    |   |-- phys
    |   |-- power
    |   |-- properties
    |   |-- subsystem -> ../../../../../../../class/input
    |   |-- uevent
    |   `-- uniq
    |-- number
    |-- pcmC0D0p
    |   |-- dev
    |   |-- device -> ../../card0
    |   |-- pcm_class
    |   |-- power
    |   |-- subsystem -> ../../../../../../../class/sound
    |   `-- uevent
    |-- pcmC0D1c
    |   |-- dev
    |   |-- device -> ../../card0
    |   |-- pcm_class
    |   |-- power
    |   |-- subsystem -> ../../../../../../../class/sound
    |   `-- uevent
    |-- pcmC0D2p
    |   |-- dev
    |   |-- device -> ../../card0
    |   |-- pcm_class
    |   |-- power
    |   |-- subsystem -> ../../../../../../../class/sound
    |   `-- uevent
    |-- pcmC0D4c
    |   |-- dev
    |   |-- device -> ../../card0
    |   |-- pcm_class
    |   |-- power
    |   |-- subsystem -> ../../../../../../../class/sound
    |   `-- uevent
    |-- pcmC0D5p
    |   |-- dev
    |   |-- device -> ../../card0
    |   |-- pcm_class
    |   |-- power
    |   |-- subsystem -> ../../../../../../../class/sound
    |   `-- uevent
    |-- pcmC0D6p
    |   |-- dev
    |   |-- device -> ../../card0
    |   |-- pcm_class
    |   |-- power
    |   |-- subsystem -> ../../../../../../../class/sound
    |   `-- uevent
    |-- pcmC0D7p
    |   |-- dev
    |   |-- device -> ../../card0
    |   |-- pcm_class
    |   |-- power
    |   |-- subsystem -> ../../../../../../../class/sound
    |   `-- uevent
    |-- power
    |   |-- async
    |   |-- autosuspend_delay_ms
    |   |-- control
    |   |-- runtime_active_kids
    |   |-- runtime_active_time
    |   |-- runtime_enabled
    |   |-- runtime_status
    |   |-- runtime_suspended_time
    |   `-- runtime_usage
    |-- subsystem -> ../../../../../../class/sound
    `-- uevent



!!Aplay/Arecord output
!!--------------------

APLAY

**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: sofsoundwire [sof-soundwire], device 0: Jack Out (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: sofsoundwire [sof-soundwire], device 2: Speaker (*) []
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: sofsoundwire [sof-soundwire], device 5: HDMI 1 (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: sofsoundwire [sof-soundwire], device 6: HDMI 2 (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: sofsoundwire [sof-soundwire], device 7: HDMI 3 (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

ARECORD

**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 0: sofsoundwire [sof-soundwire], device 1: Jack In (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: sofsoundwire [sof-soundwire], device 4: Microphone (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

!!Amixer output
!!-------------

!!-------Mixer controls for card sofsoundwire

Card sysdefault:0 'sofsoundwire'/'Intel Soundwire SOF'
  Mixer name    : 'Intel Raptorlake-P HDMI'
  Components    : 'HDA:8086281f,80860101,00100000 cfg-spk:4 cfg-amp:2 hs:rt711-sdca spk:rt1316 mic:rt715-sdca'
  Controls      : 77
  Simple ctrls  : 48
Simple mixer control 'Headphone',0
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [on]
Simple mixer control 'Speaker',0
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [on]
Simple mixer control 'IEC958',0
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [on]
Simple mixer control 'IEC958',1
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [on]
Simple mixer control 'IEC958',2
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [on]
Simple mixer control 'Headset Mic',0
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [off]
Simple mixer control 'PGA1.0 1 Master',0
  Capabilities: pvolume
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 32
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 32 [100%] [0.00dB]
  Front Right: Playback 32 [100%] [0.00dB]
Simple mixer control 'PGA2.0 2 Master',0
  Capabilities: cvolume cswitch
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Capture 0 - 80
  Front Left: Capture 50 [62%] [0.00dB] [on]
  Front Right: Capture 50 [62%] [0.00dB] [on]
Simple mixer control 'PGA3.1 3 Master',0
  Capabilities: pvolume
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 32
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 32 [100%] [0.00dB]
  Front Right: Playback 32 [100%] [0.00dB]
Simple mixer control 'PGA30.0 30',0
  Capabilities: pvolume
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 32
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 32 [100%] [0.00dB]
  Front Right: Playback 32 [100%] [0.00dB]
Simple mixer control 'PGA5.0 5 Master',0
  Capabilities: cvolume cswitch
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Capture 0 - 80
  Front Left: Capture 50 [62%] [0.00dB] [on]
  Front Right: Capture 50 [62%] [0.00dB] [on]
Simple mixer control 'PGA6.0 6 Master',0
  Capabilities: pvolume
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 32
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 32 [100%] [0.00dB]
  Front Right: Playback 32 [100%] [0.00dB]
Simple mixer control 'PGA7.0 7 Master',0
  Capabilities: pvolume
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 32
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 32 [100%] [0.00dB]
  Front Right: Playback 32 [100%] [0.00dB]
Simple mixer control 'PGA8.0 8 Master',0
  Capabilities: pvolume
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 32
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 32 [100%] [0.00dB]
  Front Right: Playback 32 [100%] [0.00dB]
Simple mixer control 'rt1316-1 DAC',0
  Capabilities: pswitch
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback [on]
  Front Right: Playback [on]
Simple mixer control 'rt1316-1 Isense Mixer',0
  Capabilities: pswitch
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback [on]
  Front Right: Playback [on]
Simple mixer control 'rt1316-1 Left I Tag Select',0
  Capabilities: volume volume-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Capture channels: Mono
  Limits: 0 - 7
  Mono: 3 [43%]
Simple mixer control 'rt1316-1 Left V Tag Select',0
  Capabilities: volume volume-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Capture channels: Mono
  Limits: 0 - 7
  Mono: 0 [0%]
Simple mixer control 'rt1316-1 RX Channel Select',0
  Capabilities: enum
  Items: 'L,R' 'L,L' 'L,R' 'L,L+R' 'R,L' 'R,R' 'R,L+R' 'L+R,L' 'L+R,R' 'L+R,L+R'
  Item0: 'L,L'
Simple mixer control 'rt1316-1 Right I Tag Select',0
  Capabilities: volume volume-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Capture channels: Mono
  Limits: 0 - 7
  Mono: 3 [43%]
Simple mixer control 'rt1316-1 Right V Tag Select',0
  Capabilities: volume volume-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Capture channels: Mono
  Limits: 0 - 7
  Mono: 1 [14%]
Simple mixer control 'rt1316-1 Vsense Mixer',0
  Capabilities: pswitch
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback [on]
  Front Right: Playback [on]
Simple mixer control 'rt1316-1 XU24 Bypass',0
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [off]
Simple mixer control 'rt1316-2 DAC',0
  Capabilities: pswitch
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback [on]
  Front Right: Playback [on]
Simple mixer control 'rt1316-2 Isense Mixer',0
  Capabilities: pswitch
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback [on]
  Front Right: Playback [on]
Simple mixer control 'rt1316-2 Left I Tag Select',0
  Capabilities: volume volume-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Capture channels: Mono
  Limits: 0 - 7
  Mono: 3 [43%]
Simple mixer control 'rt1316-2 Left V Tag Select',0
  Capabilities: volume volume-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Capture channels: Mono
  Limits: 0 - 7
  Mono: 0 [0%]
Simple mixer control 'rt1316-2 RX Channel Select',0
  Capabilities: enum
  Items: 'L,R' 'L,L' 'L,R' 'L,L+R' 'R,L' 'R,R' 'R,L+R' 'L+R,L' 'L+R,R' 'L+R,L+R'
  Item0: 'R,R'
Simple mixer control 'rt1316-2 Right I Tag Select',0
  Capabilities: volume volume-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Capture channels: Mono
  Limits: 0 - 7
  Mono: 3 [43%]
Simple mixer control 'rt1316-2 Right V Tag Select',0
  Capabilities: volume volume-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Capture channels: Mono
  Limits: 0 - 7
  Mono: 1 [14%]
Simple mixer control 'rt1316-2 Vsense Mixer',0
  Capabilities: pswitch
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback [on]
  Front Right: Playback [on]
Simple mixer control 'rt1316-2 XU24 Bypass',0
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [off]
Simple mixer control 'rt711 ADC 22 Mux',0
  Capabilities: enum
  Items: 'MIC2' 'LINE1' 'LINE2' 'DMIC'
  Item0: 'MIC2'
Simple mixer control 'rt711 ADC 23 Mux',0
  Capabilities: enum
  Items: 'MIC2' 'LINE1' 'LINE2' 'DMIC'
  Item0: 'DMIC'
Simple mixer control 'rt711 FU05',0
  Capabilities: pvolume
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 87
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 87 [100%] [0.00dB]
  Front Right: Playback 87 [100%] [0.00dB]
Simple mixer control 'rt711 FU0F',0
  Capabilities: cvolume cswitch
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Capture 0 - 63
  Front Left: Capture 58 [92%] [26.25dB] [on]
  Front Right: Capture 58 [92%] [26.25dB] [on]
Simple mixer control 'rt711 FU15 Gain',0
  Capabilities: volume
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: 0 - 3
  Front Left: 0 [0%] [0.00dB]
  Front Right: 0 [0%] [0.00dB]
Simple mixer control 'rt711 FU1E',0
  Capabilities: cvolume cswitch
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Capture 0 - 63
  Front Left: Capture 23 [37%] [0.00dB] [off]
  Front Right: Capture 23 [37%] [0.00dB] [off]
Simple mixer control 'rt711 FU44 Gain',0
  Capabilities: volume
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: 0 - 3
  Front Left: 0 [0%] [0.00dB]
  Front Right: 0 [0%] [0.00dB]
Simple mixer control 'rt714 ADC 22 Mux',0
  Capabilities: enum
  Items: 'MIC1' 'MIC2' 'LINE1' 'LINE2' 'DMIC1' 'DMIC2' 'DMIC3' 'DMIC4'
  Item0: 'DMIC3'
Simple mixer control 'rt714 ADC 23 Mux',0
  Capabilities: enum
  Items: 'MIC1' 'MIC2' 'LINE1' 'LINE2' 'DMIC1' 'DMIC2' 'DMIC3' 'DMIC4'
  Item0: 'DMIC4'
Simple mixer control 'rt714 ADC 24 Mux',0
  Capabilities: enum
  Items: 'MIC2' 'DMIC1' 'DMIC2' 'DMIC3' 'DMIC4'
  Item0: 'MIC2'
Simple mixer control 'rt714 ADC 25 Mux',0
  Capabilities: enum
  Items: 'MIC1' 'DMIC1' 'DMIC2' 'DMIC3' 'DMIC4'
  Item0: 'MIC1'
Simple mixer control 'rt714 FU02',0
  Capabilities: cvolume cswitch
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right - Rear Left - Rear Right
  Limits: Capture 0 - 127
  Front Left: Capture 119 [94%] [270.00dB] [on]
  Front Right: Capture 119 [94%] [270.00dB] [on]
  Rear Left: Capture 119 [94%] [270.00dB] [on]
  Rear Right: Capture 119 [94%] [270.00dB] [on]
Simple mixer control 'rt714 FU06',0
  Capabilities: cvolume cswitch
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right - Rear Left - Rear Right
  Limits: Capture 0 - 127
  Front Left: Capture 47 [37%] [0.00dB] [off]
  Front Right: Capture 47 [37%] [0.00dB] [off]
  Rear Left: Capture 47 [37%] [0.00dB] [off]
  Rear Right: Capture 47 [37%] [0.00dB] [off]
Simple mixer control 'rt714 FU0A',0
  Capabilities: cvolume cswitch
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Capture 0 - 127
  Front Left: Capture 47 [37%] [0.00dB] [off]
  Front Right: Capture 47 [37%] [0.00dB] [off]
Simple mixer control 'rt714 FU0C Boost',0
  Capabilities: volume
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right - Rear Left - Rear Right - Front Center - Woofer - Side Left - Side Right
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right - Rear Left - Rear Right - Front Center - Woofer - Side Left - Side Right
  Limits: 0 - 3
  Front Left: 0 [0%]
  Front Right: 0 [0%]
  Rear Left: 0 [0%]
  Rear Right: 0 [0%]
  Front Center: 0 [0%]
  Woofer: 0 [0%]
  Side Left: 0 [0%]
  Side Right: 0 [0%]
Simple mixer control 'rt714 FU0E Boost',0
  Capabilities: volume
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right - Rear Left - Rear Right - Front Center - Woofer - Side Left - Side Right
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right - Rear Left - Rear Right - Front Center - Woofer - Side Left - Side Right
  Limits: 0 - 3
  Front Left: 0 [0%]
  Front Right: 0 [0%]
  Rear Left: 0 [0%]
  Rear Right: 0 [0%]
  Front Center: 0 [0%]
  Woofer: 0 [0%]
  Side Left: 0 [0%]
  Side Right: 0 [0%]

!!All Loaded Modules
!!------------------

8250_dw
ac97_bus
acpi_pad
acpi_tad
acpi_thermal_rel
aesni_intel
af_alg
algif_hash
algif_skcipher
autofs4
binfmt_misc
bluetooth
bnep
btbcm
btintel
btmtk
btrtl
btusb
ccm
cdc_ether
cec
cfg80211
clk_tps68470
cmac
cmdlinepart
coretemp
crc32_pclmul
crct10dif_pclmul
cryptd
crypto_simd
dcdbas
dell_laptop
dell_rbtn
dell_smbios
dell_wmi
dell_wmi_ddv
dell_wmi_descriptor
dell_wmi_sysman
dm_crypt
drm
drm_buddy
drm_display_helper
drm_kms_helper
dw_dmac
dw_dmac_core
ecc
ecdh_generic
efi_pstore
firmware_attributes_class
ghash_clmulni_intel
hid
hid_generic
hid_multitouch
hid_sensor_accel_3d
hid_sensor_als
hid_sensor_custom
hid_sensor_custom_intel_hinge
hid_sensor_gyro_3d
hid_sensor_hub
hid_sensor_iio_common
hid_sensor_trigger
i2c_algo_bit
i2c_hid
i2c_hid_acpi
i2c_i801
i2c_smbus
i915
idma64
industrialio
industrialio_triggered_buffer
input_leds
int3400_thermal
int3403_thermal
int340x_thermal_zone
intel_cstate
intel_hid
intel_ish_ipc
intel_ishtp
intel_ishtp_hid
intel_lpss
intel_lpss_pci
intel_powerclamp
intel_rapl_common
intel_rapl_msr
intel_skl_int3472_discrete
intel_skl_int3472_tps68470
intel_uncore_frequency
intel_uncore_frequency_common
intel_vsec
ip_tables
iwlmvm
iwlwifi
joydev
kfifo_buf
ledtrig_audio
libarc4
lp
mac80211
mac_hid
mc
mei
mei_hdcp
mei_me
mei_pxp
mii
msr
mtd
nls_iso8859_1
nvidia
nvidia_drm
nvidia_modeset
nvidia_uvm
nvme
nvme_common
nvme_core
ov01a10
parport
parport_pc
pinctrl_tigerlake
pmt_class
pmt_telemetry
polyval_clmulni
polyval_generic
ppdev
processor_thermal_device
processor_thermal_device_pci
processor_thermal_mbox
processor_thermal_rapl
processor_thermal_rfim
psmouse
r8152
r8153_ecm
rapl
rc_core
regmap_sdw
regmap_sdw_mbq
rfcomm
rtsx_pci
rtsx_pci_sdmmc
sch_fq_codel
serio_raw
snd
snd_compress
snd_ctl_led
snd_hda_codec
snd_hda_codec_hdmi
snd_hda_core
snd_hda_ext_core
snd_hda_intel
snd_hwdep
snd_intel_dspcfg
snd_intel_sdw_acpi
snd_pcm
snd_pcm_dmaengine
snd_rawmidi
snd_seq
snd_seq_device
snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_midi_event
snd_soc_acpi
snd_soc_acpi_intel_match
snd_soc_core
snd_soc_dmic
snd_soc_hdac_hda
snd_soc_intel_hda_dsp_common
snd_soc_intel_sof_maxim_common
snd_soc_rt1316_sdw
snd_soc_rt711_sdca
snd_soc_rt715_sdca
snd_soc_sof_sdw
snd_sof
snd_sof_intel_hda
snd_sof_intel_hda_common
snd_sof_intel_hda_mlink
snd_sof_pci
snd_sof_pci_intel_tgl
snd_sof_probes
snd_sof_utils
snd_sof_xtensa_dsp
snd_timer
soundcore
soundwire_bus
soundwire_cadence
soundwire_generic_allocation
soundwire_intel
sparse_keymap
spi_intel
spi_intel_pci
spi_nor
spi_pxa2xx_platform
sunrpc
thunderbolt
tls
tps68470_regulator
ttm
typec
typec_ucsi
ucsi_acpi
usbhid
usbnet
v4l2_async
v4l2_fwnode
video
videodev
wmi
wmi_bmof
x86_pkg_temp_thermal
x_tables
xhci_pci
xhci_pci_renesas 

!!ALSA/HDA dmesg
!!--------------

[   37.657661] thermal thermal_zone13: failed to read out thermal zone (-61)
[   37.667909] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: DSP detected with PCI class/subclass/prog-if info 0x040100
[   37.668210] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: SoundWire enabled on CannonLake+ platform, using SOF driver
[   37.668716] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Invalid buffer destination
[   37.778938] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: DSP detected with PCI class/subclass/prog-if info 0x040100
[   37.779142] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: SoundWire enabled on CannonLake+ platform, using SOF driver
[   37.779169] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[   37.779434] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: DSP detected with PCI class/subclass/prog-if 0x040100
[   37.779538] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_audio_component_bind_ops [i915])
[   37.791430] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: use msi interrupt mode
[   37.828389] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: hda codecs found, mask 4
[   37.829783] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WFPM_UMAC_PD_NOTIFICATION: 0x20
--
[   37.832306] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded PNVM version e28bb9d7
[   37.834580] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: Firmware info: version 2:2:0-57864
[   37.834582] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: Firmware: ABI 3:22:1 Kernel ABI 3:23:0
[   37.834586] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: unknown sof_ext_man header type 3 size 0x30
[   37.847483] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected RF GF, rfid=0x2010d000
--
[   37.917346] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: base HW address: f0:20:ff:2d:3d:4a
[   37.932308] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: Firmware info: version 2:2:0-57864
[   37.932313] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: Firmware: ABI 3:22:1 Kernel ABI 3:23:0
[   37.936236] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3 wlp0s20f3: renamed from wlan0
--
[   37.938744] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   37.959040] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: Topology: ABI 3:22:1 Kernel ABI 3:23:0
[   37.959210] sof_sdw sof_sdw: ASoC: Parent card not yet available, widget card binding deferred
[   38.140595] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Invalid buffer destination
[   38.182524] sof_sdw sof_sdw: hda_dsp_hdmi_build_controls: no PCM in topology for HDMI converter 3
[   38.206433] input: sof-soundwire Headset Jack as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sof_sdw/sound/card0/input20
[   38.206468] input: sof-soundwire HDMI/DP,pcm=5 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sof_sdw/sound/card0/input21
[   38.206491] input: sof-soundwire HDMI/DP,pcm=6 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sof_sdw/sound/card0/input22
[   38.206514] input: sof-soundwire HDMI/DP,pcm=7 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sof_sdw/sound/card0/input23
[   38.296464] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WFPM_UMAC_PD_NOTIFICATION: 0x20


!!Packages installed
!!--------------------

ii  alsa-topology-conf                         1.2.5.1-2                                   all          ALSA topology configuration files
ii  alsa-ucm-conf                              1.2.6.3-1ubuntu1.10                         all          ALSA Use Case Manager configuration files
ii  alsa-utils                                 1.2.6-1ubuntu1                              amd64        Utilities for configuring and using ALSA
```